# How to exit nano and save to current file automatically?

Tags: command-line, nano

Whenever I close `nano` after having edited an existing file, it first asks if I'd like to save the file (which is fine), and then asks me to confirm the filename (so I press Enter, since literally 100% of the time I want to keep the same filename).

So I'm wondering, is there any shortcut I can use to avoid having to confirm the filename every time?

Comment: The correct answer is: use vim! 

Comment: If there is an editor you prefer, setting the EDITOR variable will stop most instances of automatic invocation of nano, ie sudo.

Answer (score 15):

According to [Nano manual](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/System/config_nano.htm)

You can configure `~/.nanorc` to Save automatically on exit, don't prompt

```
($:~)=> nano -w ~/.nanorc 

# Save automatically on exit, don't prompt 
set tempfile
```

> Note: as @cutrightjm commented - the above setting can cause major
>   problems in configurations if you are not careful and modify files and auto-save on exit.

Comment: Good suggestion, I would just exercise caution for newer users using this. Often times when I open up config files I'll accidentally put a character or two in it which can cause major problems in configurations if you are not careful

Comment: That's an interesting prompt they use.

Comment: @cutrightjm - thanks for the comment, I've updated my answer.

Comment: @Yaron Maybe add info on how to exit without save, discarding the changes?

Comment: The example config file with many (all?) the options is located at `/usr/share/doc/nano/examples/sample.nanorc`. Copy this file to your `~/.nanorc` and start editing from there.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2024, add `set saveonexit` to your `~/.nanorc` (.nanorc in your user dir for Windows users like me)

https://www.nano-editor.org/dist/latest/nano.html#Nanorc-Files